# UIWebView not showing/loading request

Tags: iphone, delegates, uiwebview, request

Good morning everyone,

I have an RSS reader tha opens a Detail view controller when a feed in tableView is clicked. The HTML of the feed is loaded from a items array like this in DetailController's custom setFeed() method:

```
[self.itemContent loadHTMLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@"[item objectForKey:@"content"]] baseURL:nil];
```

HTML gets loaded without any problems. If any link within is clicked the new request is loaded in the same UIWebView. The problem is that I want to show the web page in another UIWebView when a link inside itemContent is clicked.

So, what I did is I declared

```
itemContent.delegate = self
```

and in the delegate class (self) defined following method:

```
 -(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) {

    NSLog(@"Opening Outside link!!!\n");

    BrowserViewController *browserViewController = [[[BrowserViewController alloc] init] autorelease];

    //following line doesn't change anything in the result
    //browserViewController.webView.delegate = self;

    [browserViewController.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]]];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:browserViewController animated:YES]; 

    return NO;

    }

return YES;
```

}

This method definitely recognizes between loading the HTML for the first time in *itemContent* from clicks performed on the links in *itemContent* webView.
NavigationController pushes to the next View but nothing s loaded in it. I mean I've put one label next to UIWebView in the NIB file of BrowserViewController just to be sure that the NIB is loaded by seeing the label; and its showing. Also, I defined an Outlet webView connected with the UIWebView in NIB file, so this shouldn't be the problem.

If its not clear what seems to be the problem is: when the link is clicked, browserViewController is presented with the label but webView doesn't load the request.

Please, if someone could check the code provided that would be great.

I wish you a very nice day,
L

Comment: Is this your actual code? It's not even compilable, it contains "[[BrowserViewController alloc] init]];" (mismatched brackets)  -- have you simplified and chopped stuff out? Show the actual code please.

Comment: If you set a delegate for browserViewController.webView, what methods actually get called? Is a failure method called? Don't ignore your delegate methods! They are trying to tell you useful things!

Comment: Could you show us how you load the HTML in the web view?

Comment: What happens if you replace '[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:request.URL]' with '[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:@"h t  t p://google.com"]'? (Remove spaces in the HTTP btw - had to add them to stop stackoverflow munging my text)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you put a `NSLog(@"WebView: %@", browserViewController.webView);` in front of your loadRequest call you will see that the webView is nil.

The webView is not available at this time. It wasn't created in the init method.

I would suggest to add a `NSURL *url;` property to your BrowserViewController. And then instead of  `[browserViewController.webView loadRequest:...` you could use `browserViewCOntroller.url = request.URL;`. Or you could save the NSURLRequest directly.

And in the `viewDidLoad` method of the BrowserViewController you can tell the webview to load the URL, or the URLRequest.

---

But I'm just guessing.

Comment: Thank you... If I do it from Detail controller like `[browserViewController.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]]];` its not loading but if I define a NSURL *url in my BrowserViewController, then pass the value of url to it before initializing and then loading the *url from within browseViewController, then it is working! Thanks again to all of you